# Как сделать sha265-код из переменной?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

Есть переменная `cc`, значение которой задается через `input`. Есть `dict`, в котором находится зашифрованное в sha265 'abcde'. Проще говоря, это что-то вроде пароля, который зашифрован в sha265, и его необходимо сравнить с тем, что ввели в `cc`. При вводе в `cc`, при шифровании, выводится ошибка.

```
cc = input()
cc = hashlib.sha256(cc)
cc = cc.hexdigest()
if cc == dbase[cc]:
    print('It works!')
else:
    pass
```

ошибка:

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Как зашифровать эту переменную? Ну или же, как "encode" этот юникод-объект?

Comment: Во-первых, так 265 или 256? Во-вторых, у юникод-объекта есть такой метод encode, в чём проблема его вызвать?

Answer (score 1):

Хеширующие функции принимают байты как аргумент. Для кодировки  UTF-8 просто добавьте `encode` или укажите кодировку параметром:

```
cc1 = input()
cc = hashlib.sha256(cc1.encode())
cc = cc.hexdigest()
if cc1 == dbase.get(cc):
    print('It works!')
else:
    pass
```